# What statistics do you consider when choosing a layer 2 non poe access layer switch?

Tags: switch

I'm curious what others do. I'm not asking for brands or models. I don't normally use less expensive switches but realize there may be some real value in that. I also get questioned on it from time to time. Maybe I need to consider it.

Question...
When choosing a network switch what statistics do you look at? If you have the data sheets open side by side and you didn't know the brand or model you are looking at how do you choose? Let's stick to a 48 port layer 2 NON-POE at the access layer or the list could be extensive. I don't want to get to wrapped up in layer 3 features or heavy data traversal for this. Just "normal" users. I'm trying to learn from the experts.

Again, I'm not asking for brand or model recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

design wise, you should get the switch which will never cause a bottle neck in the network in the term of

- up link speed so the switch  with the 10G up link may be preferred than the 1G up link, may be the dedicated up link preferred than the dual up link.
- "Switching Bandwidth" , "Forwarding Rate" and   "switch backplane" , make use of this link [Switching Bandwidth](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/quot-switching-bandwidth-quot-and-quot-forwarding-rate-quot/td-p/2116399)
- multicast traffic, where normal users traffic will be treated way else then multicast traffic (CCTV, IP came ..).so if you will deal with multicast traffic you need to make sure that multicast protocols are supported in this switch (IGMP V2, IGMP V3 ,...)

Comment: That link is great! Considering multicast is a good observation. I seen this comment in that link. Have you experienced this in the "real world"? I'm normally dealing with enterprise switches though. It's not like I'd put a 200 switch at a san but I've never replaced a switch with like up link speeds to gain an improvement in speed...... Low-end GbE switches may have 1 Gbps/port switching bandwidth only if you send large packets (1500 kB). If you're sending small packets (like voice traffic), the bandwidth will be much slower because of the poor forwarding rate.

Comment: regarding to experience, we faced two cases before. first  where we
suggested a model rather than model cause of its multicast ability
, second was multicast performance issue on running network and the resolution was to configure STP MST rather than PVST . by the nature you may found switches designed to handle certain type of traffic such SAN switches
which can handle storage data and its MTUs. even if you grantee that
the end connected device to this switch will send a few traffic
it will still considered as a bottle neck if you don't uplink them with 
bigger pipe.

Comment: I've also seen multicast issues. I have a multicast love hate relationship. But, I've never seen a switch handle small packets so poorly that a replacement switch with the same port and uplink speeds was the resolution. My comment is based on that quote from my previous comment. Thank you for your answer and time. I like to learn from other network engineers /architects.